# Proper pattern to use a method declared in a service while working in template of a component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, service, scope

In most of my components, I'm using FontAwesome and declare them for usage as follows.

```
import * as fa from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
...
@Component({ ... })
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: SirService) { }
  add = fa.faPlus;
  ...
  }
}
```

In the actual template I have something like this.

```
<fa-icon [icon]="add" ...></fa-icon>
```

Now, I want to centralize the icon management and outsource it to the service, so I can obtain them using the following syntax instead.

```
constructor(private sir: SirService) { }
add = this.sir.willGiveMeIconFor("add"); ...
```

This far, everything is obvious to me. Now, however, I can't decide if I should rely on the assignment as shown above or rather expose the whole service to the template. Since I have to make the service publicly available for the template to see it, I'd have to use something like this.

```
constructor(private sir: SirService) { this source = sir; }
public icons: SirService;
//add = this.sir.willGiveMeIconFor("add"); ...
```

And in the template (after renaming the method in the service to make better semantics, of course).

```
<fa-icon [icon]="icons.show('add')" ...></fa-icon>
```

I've been told that declaring the service as public in the constructor is bad practice. I also sense that I'm keeping multiple references to it for no apparent reason. Since I've not done things using that strategy, I feel careful not to run ahead hitting a wall further on.

I've also considered using a totally different approach - e.g. by a directive or a pipe. However, I don't feel confident enough to make the judgement call. Since such a reconstruction would be rather extensive, I prefer to understand the theory before I go into implementation of it.

The closest to my issue I've found was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55243579/angular-7-problem-while-trying-to-using-a-method-service-in-a-component) but it not even nearly informative enough to ease my worry.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by defining precisely what is our need here.

- We do not want to switch over to other component to support this (then injecting service as You have shown),
- We do not want to have that kind of service in all compnoents that are using FA (it feels like far more to write that we would gain from it),
- I would argue if this service is needed as a logical part of those components,
- As a final effect we want to have a value pulled from a service to the `[icon]` directive and I think this is the answer to follow the convention.

I would then create a shared directive called `myApp-fa-icon` or something like that and put there a service, maybe even expose some enum for the icons in the app, as right now we are really switching from string solution to another string solution (but centralised). Then inside this directive I would accept only that enum, not a string (but there comes the chore of having this enum imported in every component when You wany to do something dynamically with icon but on the other hand it will narrow the list of icons to be used).

And for creating service public You don't need to reassign it to the public field, just set it `public` inside the constructor if You want.

Edit: I also have thought about pipe as You suggested but I can only see one major benefit that would come from using it: pure pipes. I assume that those icons won't change so most of the time pipe won't be evaluated but...

1. It would look awkward: `[icon]="add | my-icon"`
2. If we are stubborn, we can declare a parameterless directive that will get the input of `[icon]` as the `@Input()` and `ngOnChanges()` we can just skip all the logic (so something like this: `<fa-icon [myApp-fa-icon] [icon]="add" ...></fa-icon>` but yet again - it looks bit strange to me.
3. Does it really make a difference? It is not like determinating an icon is a very heavy operation to perform.

Edit:

Ok, I create an emaple myselft and I must said I tend toward creation of custom component that will serve like a proxy for `fa-icon`. It is far less complicated and more readable than usage of directive.

1) directive would just hijack the `[icon]` attribute's value, replace it with one loaded from the service and force Angular to detect changes to make `fa-icon`'s `icon` directive to do it's work. Way over complicated, sorry I thought `fa-icon` element is working a little bit different.

Here is the working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgcwdu?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: SO, to verify that I got you correctly. You're not in favor of injecting a service to provide the icons. You suggest directive based approach. Correct? So, lets say I throw in a directive - how would it determine which icon is to be produced? Are you saying that you'd use a different directive for each type of icon? Perhaps you could show a line or two presenting how it would be used. (I can work out the directive parts by the docs.)

Comment: To elaborate on my request - according to [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#directives-overview) there are three types of directives and when I read the definition of them, I kind of recognize your suggestion in each and every one. So I'm not certain I understood your point sufficiently well.

Comment: Hi, I have to leave now and I'll provide some example later (within 2 hours) but if You are interested You can take a look at `src/app/highlight.directive.ts (excerpt)` example in that doc, inject a service and give a proper icon to look for by the `@Input()`.

Comment: @KonradViltersten see my updated answer, the very bottom of it.